# What setting controls this feature in my .dialogrc file?

Tags: bash, dialog

I'm writing a bash script for personal use that uses [dialog](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog). My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                              
DIALOG=${DIALOG=dialog}

$DIALOG --title "Title" --clear \
    --msgbox "hello world" 18 64
clear
```

Running the script produces a menu that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to change the way the choice `OK` is highlighted. Ideally I'd like the whole `OK` "button" outlined or the text to change color when selected but I would settle for the highlighting of the `O` to be a different color. The settings are controlled by my `.dialogrc` file which  is given below.

```
#
# Run-time configuration file for dialog
#
# Automatically generated by "dialog --create-rc <file>"
#
#
# Types of values:
#
# Number     -  <number>
# String     -  "string"
# Boolean    -  <ON|OFF>
# Attribute  -  (foreground,background,highlight?)

# Set aspect-ration.
aspect = 0

# Set separator (for multiple widgets output).
separate_widget = ""

# Set tab-length (for textbox tab-conversion).
tab_len = 0

# Make tab-traversal for checklist, etc., include the list.
visit_items = OFF

# Shadow dialog boxes? This also turns on color.
use_shadow = OFF

# Turn color support ON or OFF
use_colors = OFF

# Screen color
screen_color = (CYAN,BLUE,ON)

# Shadow color
shadow_color = (BLACK,BLACK,ON)

# Dialog box color
dialog_color = (BLACK,WHITE,OFF)

# Dialog box title color
title_color = (BLUE,WHITE,ON)

# Dialog box border color
border_color = (WHITE,WHITE,ON)

# Active button color
button_active_color = (WHITE,BLUE,ON)

# Inactive button color
button_inactive_color = dialog_color

# Active button key color
button_key_active_color = button_active_color

# Inactive button key color
button_key_inactive_color = (RED,WHITE,OFF)

# Active button label color
button_label_active_color = (YELLOW,BLUE,ON)

# Inactive button label color
button_label_inactive_color = (BLACK,WHITE,ON)

# Input box color
inputbox_color = dialog_color

# Input box border color
inputbox_border_color = dialog_color

# Search box color
searchbox_color = dialog_color

# Search box title color
searchbox_title_color = title_color

# Search box border color
searchbox_border_color = border_color

# File position indicator color
position_indicator_color = title_color

# Menu box color
menubox_color = dialog_color

# Menu box border color
menubox_border_color = border_color

# Item color
item_color = dialog_color

# Selected item color
item_selected_color = button_active_color

# Tag color
tag_color = title_color

# Selected tag color
tag_selected_color =  button_label_active_color

# Tag key color
tag_key_color = button_key_inactive_color

# Selected tag key color
tag_key_selected_color = (RED,BLUE,ON)

# Check box color
check_color = dialog_color

# Selected check box color
check_selected_color = button_active_color

# Up arrow color
uarrow_color = (GREEN,WHITE,ON)

# Down arrow color
darrow_color = uarrow_color

# Item help-text color
itemhelp_color = (WHITE,BLACK,OFF)

# Active form text color
form_active_text_color = button_active_color

# Form text color
form_text_color = (WHITE,CYAN,ON)

# Readonly form item color
form_item_readonly_color = (CYAN,WHITE,ON)

# Dialog box gauge color
gauge_color = title_color

# Dialog box border2 color
border2_color = dialog_color

# Input box border2 color
inputbox_border2_color = dialog_color

# Search box border2 color
searchbox_border2_color = dialog_color

# Menu box border2 color
menubox_border2_color = dialog_color
```

Is it possible to edit this file to get my desired result? I've tried changing a few of the settings but everything I've tried has either resulted in no change or an error.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a chromebook using crouton.

Comment: When you think that one of these below answers fits your needs, please accept it and I'll give the bounty to that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The highlighting of the "O" in your screenshot is the terminal's cursor. You can't control its appearance, it's rendered according to each user's terminal settings.

For example, here is how it appears in the OS X terminal with the default cursor style ("Block cursor"): [image: Block cursor]
Here it is with the cursor style changed to "Vertical bar": [image: Vertical Bar cursor]
Here it is with the cursor made invisible by running `tput civis` before the dialog command (and `tput cnorm` to make it visible again after the dialog run):[image: Invisible cursor]

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but you might be rather interested in dialog alternative - whiptail

[image]

As for your dialocrc file, the line `button_label_active_color = (YELLOW,BLUE,ON)` might be what you wanna